# Can I run my Macbook Pro on an external battery?

Tags: macbook-pro, battery

My Macbook Pro 15" Retina (late 2019) stopped working suddenly the other. I took it to an Apple technician and he says that there is a problem with the motherboard or something like that. They quoted for a replacement and it costs an arm and a leg. For now, they have disabled/bypassed the battery allowing me to work while I'm plugged in. It will have to do for now as I'm not prepared to pay the cost of the repair. The hassle is that it's a bit slower (I can live with that) and whenever I need to move, I have to shut down.
Is it possible to run it on an external battery and not plugged in?

Answer (score 1):

> he says that there is a problem with the motherboard or something like
> that

It sounds like the problem is the battery, not the logic board. It's probably worth taking note of exactly what the technician says, in order to make the correct decision.

> Is it possible to run it on an external battery and not plugged in?

There are batteries with an 85W USB output. However, whether they will work as a power source in the absence of a battery is doubtful. You would at least get severe throttling.

Also, their price ranges from (in the UK) £100 - £220 (depending on size/time), which isn't that much off the £199 that Apple charges for a battery replacement.

Answer (score 0):

You could consider deep cycle batteries (designed for leisure use, not starting cars) and a 12V or 24V inverter to produce the 230V AC or 110V AC.

How much this will cost depends on several factors. Also it is not going to be easy to transport.